# Using setTimeout() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not new to Javascript but then I realize I don't know how to use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout('changeit()',1000); // I have also tried setTimeout('changeit',1000);
  // var t = setTimeout('changeit()',1000); <--- tried also something like this.

  // changeit(); <-- works when i do this.

  function changeit(){
    $('#hello').html('Hello World - this was inserted using jQuery');
    // #hello is <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  }
})
```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a reference to the `changeit` function instead of a string of JavaScript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeit, 1000);
    function changeit() {
        $("#hello").html("Hello world - this was inserted using jQuery.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
setTimeout(changeit, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(changeit, 1000);
});

function changeit() {
  $('#hello').html('Hello World - this was inserted using jQuery');
}
```

or this:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(changeit, 1000);
  function changeit() {
    $('#hello').html('Hello World - this was inserted using jQuery');
  }
});
```

The problem with your version is that you're passing a string to `setTimeout()` which is eval'ed but by that time `changeit()` is out of scope so it won't work.

The alternative is to make `changeit` global (as per the first code snippet).